# How to get user contact ids for deletion?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm developing an integration for Sendgrid contacts and the [upsert](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact) is doing fine. The problem is how to get user ids to [delete](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/delete-contacts) them. Right now the upsert is not the only way to add contacts into our contacts list ([to search id by email](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/get-contacts-by-emails) as soon as I insert a user), so I need a way to bulk get the contact ids.

How can I do that without using list/segments and not having to [bulk download](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/export-contacts) every time?